# Can't detect shapes from the webcam

Tags: opencv, shapes, detect, rectangles

I want to find how many vertex exist and determine the shape by the number of vertecies. So far, I have been able to detect whether a circle exists or doesn't by using 'HoughCircle', but I can not cope with rectangle, square or triangle.

Here's the code, but I couldn't done it.

```
// declerations
vector<vector<Point>> contoursPoly(contours.size());
vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
Mat contourimg;
Mat frame, out;

// for webcam
VideoCapture vcap(0);

for (;;){

    vcap.read(frame);  // display 
    cvtColor(frame, out, CV_BGR2GRAY);  // convert BGR to GRAY scale

    // fix noises
    GaussianBlur(out, out, Size(9, 9), 2);
    threshold(out,out,200,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    findContours(out, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);  // find contours

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contoursPoly[i], 3, true); // find the number of vertecies

        if (contoursPoly.size() == 4) // it should be a quadrilateral
        {
            boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contoursPoly[i]);
            drawContours(frame, contours, i, Scalar(0, 0, 255), CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
        }

        if (contoursPoly.size() == 3)  // it should be triange
        {
            drawContours(frame, contours, i, Scalar(0, 0, 255), CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
        }

    imshow("test", frame);
    if (waitKey(30) == 27) break;
```

EDIT :

I have made some changes..

1. vector contoursPoly(contours.size());
2. approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contoursPoly, arcLength(Mat(contours[i])*0.01, true), true);

and here is the images from the program..

[image]

EDIT 2 :

Thanks to the comments, I've added this part to my code : 
Mat contourOutput = threshimg.clone();

and I've got this recently..

[image]

But there is still a problem. It does not draw the contours, thats why cannot detect shapes.

EDIT 3 : I have also done what I want by Hough Lines and here is the result :

[image]

This is the code :

```
int main(){

    VideoCapture vcap(0);
    Mat gray, frame, mask, out, trackbarimg;

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Point> contPoly;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    RotatedRect rrect;
    Point2f vertices[4];

    for (;;){

        vcap.read(frame);
        cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(gray,gray,Size(9,9), 1);
        threshold(gray, mask, 220, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        Mat contoursOut = mask.clone();
        findContours(contoursOut, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        out = Mat::zeros(contoursOut.size(), CV_8UC3);

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
            drawContours(out, contours, i, Scalar(0, 255, 0), CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy, 1, Point());
            rrect = minAreaRect(contours[i]);

            rrect.points(vertices);
            line(out, vertices[0], vertices[1], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
            line(out, vertices[1], vertices[2], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
            line(out, vertices[2], vertices[3], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
            line(out, vertices[3], vertices[0], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        }

        imshow("THRESHOLD", mask);
        imshow("BLUR", gray);
        imshow("ORIGINAL", frame);
        imshow("LINES", out);   

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Are there any illogical things or mistakes in the second code ? Actually, I want make my purpose happen by using approxPolyDP and determine how many vertices there are.

Comment: Try `approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contoursPoly[i], 0.01*arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true), true);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it did not work.

Comment: Then please provide some sample images. Rhe source, the binary inage after thresholding and the detected contours

Comment: And check contoursPoly[i].size()

Comment: it didn't work also.. I've provided images..

Comment: Be aware that findContours modifies your source image, thats why your threshold image looks like that! So maybe pass a copy!

Comment: And i dont get you second edit. contours is a vector<vector<Point>> with all your contours.  Contours[i] is one of those contours with x-points. So why `vector contoursPoly(contours.size());` ?

Comment: You have to check and approx every contour inside `contours`

Comment: PSchn, thanks for your comments. The program is getting better. Please check edit 2.

Comment: You use hierarchy in drawContours but you generated no hierarchy in findContours. So just write `drawContours(out, contours, i, Scalar(0, 255, 0), CV_FILLED, 8)`

Comment: And to draw a rectangle you can use [`rectangle`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle)

Comment: And whats going wrong now? your images are looking great, easy to segment.

Comment: I've used rectangle() func. and added some new things. It workes. But, it cannot detect whether the object is triangle and when the program detects another quadrilateral, it does not keep tracking the main object.
Here is the code : http://www.codesend.com/view/0da9c74e4f93942ca89e10ca6413e419/ and here is the results : http://i63.tinypic.com/10xsyzs.jpg

Comment: link is broken!

Comment: Sorry, this one is not broken :  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3390899f4b17f059df72c4ba7544c363

Comment: PSchn.. Now, I am able to find a quadrilateral. But the problem is, the program cannot detect shapes which I want to find if they are not bright. Like a phone screen.

Comment: Your threshold with 200 is very high, try to decrease it.

Answer (score 0):

Finding shapes by contours relies on the outline not being broken by something (like your thumb in the example).

A more robust alternative would be to use the hough transform to find lines (or line segments) and then check which lines intersect to form squares/rectangles.

If you want to use contours, I would run approxPolyDP in a loop, increasing the approximation factor until you get a contour with 4 points - or it fails.

Comment: Could you check EDIT 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that after you do the thresholding (and before the findContour()), you need to do an edge detection, for example using a Canny Edge Detector:

```
void cv::Canny  (InputArray image, OutputArray  edges, double threshold1, double threshold2, int apertureSize = 3, bool L2gradient = false)
```

Documentation on canny is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de).

Comment: It still can not draw contours.

Comment: I think in the for loop, you should test for  contoursPoly[i].size() not contoursPoly.size() ?